# Cannot enable Hyper-V Platform

Tags: platform, hyper-v

I am trying to enable Hyper-V in my local machine running Windows 8 Enterprise Ed 64-bit. I checked and my hardware is SLAT-compatible, the option in BIOS is turned on. I did several cold boot but the Hyper-V platform option still remains grayed out. I hope someone can help me since all the blogs/forums that seems to address this issue did not solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you hover your mouse over the Hyper-V item in the Optional Features list, it will tell you why it's disabled.

Otherwise, you can run MSINFO32.EXE and the System Summary panel will list the features required for Hyper-V and whether or not those features have been detected on your system.

Also, you said you've cold-booted the system a few times.  This might sound stupid, but shut your system down and unplug it for a few minutes to make sure it's actually off before plugging it in and turning it on again.  I've never seen a system where I had to do this, but I know other people who have.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Data Exeuction Prevention ?
Control panel - System - System Properties -Data Exeuction Prevention